COROS Error Still Ouccr after installed the laravel fruitcake/laravel-cors
I have set up the packages in Laravel.
It was working for a certain level, but if it has more than 10 or 20 rows of data, it will experience the same error as Coros.

Laravel should natively handle CORS already. We need more information in order to help you.
https://laravel.com/docs/11.x/routing#cors
